# Concatenation of strings in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have feature in a dataframe that stores the class information of students like:

```
Student_ID  CLass
S1           5
S2           7
S3           6
```

How can I prefix characters like `C_` before the `Class` for every student?

Comment: Please add what you've tried already, how you currently store the information in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I understood that you want to add prefix `C_` to all values of `class` column.

If that is the case (your prefix is constant `C_`) , you can do something like

```
df['CLass'] = 'C_' + df['CLass'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using the apply method of pandas dataframes like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([5, 6, 7], index = ["S1", "S2", "S3"], columns = ["Class"])
df["Class"].apply(lambda x: "C_" + str(x))
```

**Output:**

```
S1    C_5
S2    C_6
S3    C_7
Name: Class, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for [pd.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html). Typically, it can be faster to use the special string methods for Series of strings, but I can't think of an easy way to leverage those for prepending.

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Student_ID": ["S1", "S2", "S3"], "Class":[5,7,6]})
>>> df
  Student_ID  Class
0         S1      5
1         S2      7
2         S3      6
>>> df['Class'] = df['Class'].astype(str)
>>> df['Class'] = df['Class'].apply(lambda n: 'C_' + n)
>>> df
  Student_ID Class
0         S1   C_5
1         S2   C_7
2         S3   C_6
```